# Как выделить цветом элемент массива

Tags: c++, c

Имеется матрица, и в ней необходимо выделить другим цветом (допустим зелёным) главную диагональ. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Есть натуральные числа. Как сделать четные зелеными? Ну по-дурацки же вопрос формулируете!!

Answer (score 2):

Я опустил ввод матрицы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int mat[n][n];
    //ввод матрицы
    HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if(i == j){
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, FOREGROUND_GREEN); //печатаем зеленым
                cout << a[i][j];
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, FOREGROUND_WHITE); //печатаем белым
            } else cout << a[i][j];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Решение разумеется не кросплатформенное, почитать о `SetConsoleTextAttribute` можно [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers#_win32_character_attributes)

Comment: ТС хоть раз упомянул слова "Windows", "консоль", наконец, просто "вывод"?

Comment: @Harry нет, но из контекста понятно что он хочет цветной вывод в консоль, а я уже предложил ему решение которое знаю

Comment: Мой вопрос был риторическим :)